# Польза и нельзя ― исторически родственные слова?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Согласно этимологическим словарям, эти слова имеют общий корень с прилагательным ***легкий***, но как это объяснить с точки зрения семантики?

Как слова ***польза*** и ***нельзя*** получили свое современное значение и когда они появились в русском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Польза (фиксируется уже в рус. языке XI–XVII вв.): облегчение —> выгода —> благо.

Нельзя (известно уже в рус. языке XI–XVII вв.): из *не есть льзя, т. е. не свободно —> не разрешено.

Легкий (от *льга*), очевидно, связано с идеей легкости, а идея свободы — совсем рядом.

Comment: "Свобода" даже ближе. От того же древнего корня было образовано "льгота", которое имело среди значений "свобода", "освобождение" и, возможно даже, "разрешение" (по словарю Черных).

Comment: @grizzly ну да, но я ведь написал, что «идея свободы — совсем рядом»?)

Comment: Я не критики ради :) хотел только дополнить словом "льгота" и названием источника.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Легкий как освобожденный от чего-либо тяжелого, затем легкий как свободный для собственных действий. Поэтому льзя - это свобода делать то, что хочешь. Но одно из первых слов, которое слышит малое дитя, - это "нельзя!" Так нам указывают на то, насколько мы несвободны в этом мире.

Answer (score 2):

Мать говорит ребёнку: Нельзя! И отбирает камушек, который он хочет положить в рот. Потом даёт своему чаду морковку со словами: Кушай! От морковки польза! То есть,  нельзя - это запрет, а польза - можно. Нельзя - не лезет, то есть выйдет обратно из организма. А полезет в рот - принесёт пользу, благо. Лекарство не в пользу - заболел живот, значит, такое лекарство  не лезет в горло, то есть нельзя пить такое лекарство. Яд - нельзя, а  свежие овощи - польза.  Теперь можно утверждать, что слова польза и нельзя исторически родственные слова.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, что *можно* и *возможно* близки и в чём-то взаимозаменяемы с *легко*, но *нельзя* и *нелегко* — категории неравновесные. Связь с определением *лёгкий* здесь трудно уловить, и она подчёркивается большинством источников только по отношению к сущ. *польза*, «заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является преф. производным от льга (см. легкий); г > з по третьему смягчению заднеязычных».

В НКРЯ *нельзя* отмечено 1694 годом, а *польза* — 1700-м.

Одно из значений слова, которое выглядит однокоренным не могу не привести.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Польза, нельзя, - это всё относится к действию "лыко драть". Лыко драть по болгарски - лико сълза, lyko slza - в переводе на словацкий. Встречал переводы "к полизанью", "да полижешь". Когда лыко драли слизывали сладкую соковину. Польза - когда было что полизать. Нельзя - когда нечего лизать. Мать говорила ребёнку тянущему всё в рот - нельзя, то есть не лижи горькое.
По болгарски лыко сълза и слеза - сълза. Так же на итальянском слеза и лыко одно слово - lacrima.

Полизал сладкий сок - польза.

польский

драть лыко - rozerwać łyka – глотнуть

собирались лыко драть - mieli się rozerwać - они должны были повеселиться

пошли за лыком - podążaj za łykiem - сделать глоток

хорватский

лыко драть - Bast suza - Просто слеза

чешский

драть лыко - roztrhat lýko - слезинка

Answer (score -1):

Польза, нельзя, служба - от лоз,лоуз -  нужный. 
По- указывает на неоднократное однородные действия, события. Из формулы нечто бя нечто по -нечто к нечто одинаковому,один к одному.
Не -отрицание, лоуз -нужный - не нужно.
С -в русском языке -побуждение к действию, лоуз- нужный, бе - будь. Будь нужным.
Из языка роси, сегодня в талышском, азербайджанском. В талышском - оригинал от даев.

Comment: Словарь талышско - русского языка Л. Пирейко

Answer (score -1):

Думается, что «польза» и «нельзя» не просто слова одного корня, важно что это слова – антонимы. Поскольку слова «полегче» и «нелегко» антонимами не являются, возникают сомнения, что слова «польза» и «нельзя» имеют общий корень с прилагательным «легкий». По меньшей мере, стоило бы поискать более близких форм для этих слов…

Если отталкиваться от понятия «все на свете пробовать языком», а одним словом - лизать (лизнуть вскользь/слегка), то без каких либо натяжек, рекомендации «полижи» (польза) и «не лижи» (нельзя) могут считаться антонимами (мамины, - разрешение или запрет).

Отметим и то, что корни «лиз» и «льз» хоть на чуть-чуть, но ближе друг к другу, чем к «льг».